# 50-udev-default.rules: Unknown builtin command: net_driver, lost internet connection

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, network-interface, udev, pacman

I'm running an Arch-based distro, and after doing a substantial update lost my internet connection (both wifi and ethernet). I'm able to roll back all of the changes and get it back, but would obviously like to be able to get to the source of the issue. For what it's worth, other users of the distro do not seem to be having the same issue.

After updating, `jounalctl -p 3 -xb` gives me:

```
systemd-udevd[750]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:29 Unknown builtin command: net_driver
(udev-worker)[2083754]:  event14: Failed to call EVIOSKEYCODE with scan code 0x7c, and key code 190: Invalid argument
systemd-udevd[750]: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:29 Unknown builtin command: net_driver
(sd-pam)[2107125]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to release session: Access denied
(sd-pam)[2107144]: pam_systemd(login:session): Failed to release session: Access denied
```

`/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:29` is this line of code:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", IMPORT{builtin}="net_driver"
```

which makes sense, given that an unidentified `net_driver` command seems to be the source of the problem.

The systemctl NetworkManager reads that I'm connected to the internet (and the connection is not marked as "unmanaged"), and `nmcli` also shows it. There is simply no connectivity - `ping` 100% fails, including `ping 1.1.1.1`, so it isn't just a DNS issue, and obviously no site will load.

This is my first time needing to dive into `udev` on my own, and I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm looking at. I figure I've got two ways forward:

1. Ignore the problem, isolate the offending package(s), don't update them, and update everything else, and hope that a fix happens down the line, allowing me to update them at some point in the future
2. Discover the root issue and fix it

I'm not sure how to accomplish either of these. For the first, I assume I'm looking for a driver or boot update, and there is a `grub` update on the list. That being said, I'm not sure how to isolate, or even to really narrow down which packages it might be. (There were over 100 in the update.)

For the second approach, I'm not sure if the `udev` rule was updated in a way that broke everything or if the issue is somewhere else. In the current syntax of `50-udev-default.rules` it clearly expects `net_driver` to be defined elsewhere (or at least prior to what is currently line 29); where would that be? Is this the kind of thing one even messes with or, in the words of Boromir, does one not simply "mess" with udev?

Please let me know if there's additional information I can supply to help figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: When you say ping fails, what are you pinging? Domains or IP addresses? I'm just wondering if it could be a DNS issue. Does `ping 8.8.8.8` work, for example?

Comment: @terdon I was using 1.1.1.1 (100% packet loss)

Comment: [`net_driver`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/2b5b25f123ceb89b3ff45b2380db1c8a88b046d9) is a new builtin that was added [recently](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/29624)... If you can see it listed among other builtins when running `udevadm test-builtin --help` then I would say this is a bug... So maybe rollback and wait for the fix (fwiw, I'm on `systemd 254.6-2` , I don't have this builtin and everything works ok)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking @don_crissti 's advice and rolled back the systemd changes. (I have [Snapper](https://snapper.io/), so it was as simple as rolling back to a snapshot before the update.) That was enough to get the internet connection functional. I was able to update again roughly a week afterwards without issue.

I'd consider this more of a placeholder answer since it doesn't actually get to the heart of the issue, and is more of a workaround. As such, it's unlikely to help people who are on a distro that has had this rule for longer.